# HTML|CSS: Space between input buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in which I have a space between these two buttons.

The code is as follows:

```
<input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" />
<input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" />

.PostBtn
{
   background: url(../Images/Buttons/PostButtonF.png) no-repeat;
   width: 50px;
   height: 28px;
   border: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#NeedBtn
{
   background-position: 0 0;
}
#ProvBtn
{
   background-position: -50px 0;
}
```

How do I remove that space?

Browser:
Firefox 3.5

IE8

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The line feed between the two `<input>`s creates a space between them on the page. You have to remove the line feed, or use this trick :

```
<input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" /><!--
--><input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" />
```

Comment: The line feed is causing the space, he means to type it like this: <input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" /><input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" /> instead of having them on separate lines.

Comment: Put <input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" /><input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" /> on one line.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't use clear words, English isn't my native language.

Comment: Also, if you need to have them on different lines for code organization, try this... <input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" [newline]/><input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" />

Comment: You don't have to. Here's the trick I'm using (a bit like Kerrick's, but more elegant I think) : `<input ... /><!-- [newline here] --><input ... />`

Comment: Using a comment block is a poor substitute for using CSS properties (float, or display), like other answers did. This is hacky, and won't help solve any future grid-alignment problems.

Answer (score 25):

Surprised no one mentioned this method yet:

The problem is the white-space between the two buttons is being rendered. Any white-space (line breaks, tabs, spaces) between the buttons will be rendered as a single space by the browser. To fix this, you can set the `font-size` to 0 on a parent element.

I've added `DIV#button-container` around the buttons and a style for it showing the `font-size` trick.

Note: I also had to change the positioning on the button background graphic you linked since it had some extra pixel space around it. Maybe this was part of the problem, maybe not.

Here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHhnB/ and the code:

```
<style>
#button-container
{
   font-size:0;    
}
.PostBtn
{
   background: url(http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/5066/capturebtn.png) no-repeat;
   width: 50px;
   height: 28px;
   border: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#NeedBtn
{
   background-position: -4px 0;
}
#ProvBtn
{
   background-position: -59px 0px;
}
</style>
<div id="button-container">
    <input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" />
    <input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn" type="button" />
</div>
```

Comment: This answer helped me realize that you have to delete not only the line feed, but also any indenting you had on the next line.

Comment: Neat. I'd used float, but this can be better in some circumstances. If you have text in the container you're screwed though.

Comment: You can make a separate container inside the `font-size:0` container for text and change the font size to whatever you want. The only problem using  this method is you lose font size inheritance. i.e. if you have a 14pt size on your body, you have to redefine it on these inner text containers.

Comment: Obs: safari doesn't accept 0px font-size in this case. I've tested on other browsers and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out you can use floats to counter act the whitespace between elements

```html
<input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn floated" type="button" />
<input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn floated" type="button" />
```

```css
.floated {
   float:left;
}
```

```css
.floated {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn floated" value="Next" type="button" />
<input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn floated" value="Prev" type="button" />
```

As well as the various hacks for inline-block:

1. Using 0px font-size in parent and resetting the font-size in the child elements.

```html
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Some Text</div>
        <div class="child">Some More Text</div>
    </div>
```

```css
    .parent {
       font-size:0px;
     }

     .parent > * {
       display:inline-block;
       font-size:14px;
     }
```

2. Putting all the elements next to each other, ie: `<div></div><div></div>`
3. Putting the closing tag on the next line and next to the next element, ie:

   ```
   <div>
   </div><div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Putting the closing bracket of the previous element on the next line and next to the next element, ie:

   ```
   <div></div
   ><div></div>
   ```
5. Or using html comments

   ```
   <div></div><!--
   --><div></div>
   ```

And as stated by others this isn't an optimal solution.

With modern browsers Flexbox styles can now be used

```html
<div class="flex">
    <input id="NeedBtn" class="PostBtn flex-child" type="button" />
    <input id="ProvBtn" class="PostBtn flex-child" type="button" />
</div>
```

```css
.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -moz-box-flex:  0 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex:  0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex:  0 1 auto;
    flex:  0 1 auto;
}
```

```css
.flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -moz-box-flex:  0 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex:  0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex:  0 1 auto;
    flex:  0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <input type="button" class="flex-child" id="slide_start_button" value="Start">
    <input type="button" class="flex-child" id="slide_stop_button"  value="Stop">
</div>
```

A guide for flex can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and support list [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 8):

You can use css to fix it. Set float:left or float:right on the input buttons. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I had the Buttons in table cells and they were adding pesky extra space.  Giving them float: left fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Try using a CSS reset - it may solve the browser discrepancy : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Answer (score 1):

I see they have a set height and width. Adding overflow: hidden should hide the whitespace outside of your defined width. That is an alternative to eliminating the whitespace, as @Pikrass noted. Usually the whitespace is a IE problem, I've not noticed it in FF before.